# How can I launch a Chrome App through another Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome App. When I click a button in there, I want to launch another Chrome App. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first app, send a message to the second app using [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage). When the second app gets it, do whatever you would have done in that app's [`chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle#eventpage) handler.